# DefaultClusterRenderer getMarker() returning null when zooming

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

I want to change the background of the cluster marker on click. I do this via

```
@Override
onClusterClick(Cluster<MyObject> cluster) {
    Marker marker = renderer.getMarker(cluster);
    marker.setIcon(....);
}
```

This works fine expect for one case: When I zoom in or out and the number of cluster markers doesn't change. For example, if I had a 15 cluster and a 5 cluster, then zoom a level in or out, the same two clusters remain. Clicking on one of these now `renderer.getMarker(cluster)` returns null. If they re-cluster after zooming, getMarker is not null.

My DefaultClusterRenderer is below. I checked the marker on `onClusteredRendered` and it's never null. Is this a bug in the DefaultClusterRenderer or should I do something else?

```
private class MyRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyObject> {

    private IconGenerator iconGenerator;
    private float density;

    public MyRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<MyObject> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
        density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyObject item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_pin));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyObject> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        if(iconGenerator == null) {
            iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(getActivity());
            iconGenerator.setContentView(makeTextView(getActivity()));
        }
        iconGenerator.setBackground(makeBackground(false));

        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()))));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterRendered(Cluster<MyObject> cluster, Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterRendered(cluster, marker);
        // Marker is never null here

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<MyObject> cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize() > 1;
    }

    private ShapeDrawable makeBackground(boolean isClicked) {
        ShapeDrawable background = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        background.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),
                isClicked ? R.color.cluster_marker_clicked : R.color.cluster_marker_unclicked), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        return background;
    }

    private SquareTextView makeTextView(Context context) {
        SquareTextView squareTextView = new SquareTextView(context);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-2, -2);
        squareTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        squareTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white));

        squareTextView.setTypeface(Utils.getFontBold(getActivity()));

        squareTextView.setId(com.google.maps.android.R.id.text);
        int twelveDpi = (int) (12.0F * density);
        squareTextView.setPadding(twelveDpi, twelveDpi, twelveDpi, twelveDpi);

        return squareTextView;
    }

    public IconGenerator getIconGenerator(boolean isClicked) {
        iconGenerator.setBackground(makeBackground(isClicked));
        return iconGenerator;
    }
}
```

Initializing the ClusterManager:

```
    final ClusterManager<MyObject> mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(getActivity(), googleMap);
    mClusterManager.addItems(items);

    renderer = new CustomRenderer(getActivity(), googleMap, mClusterManager);
    mClusterManager.setRenderer(renderer);
    mClusterManager.cluster();

    mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this);

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
```

@antonio: This initialization is working for me:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyObject> {

    // ...

    private void setUpClusterer() {
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.503186, -0.126446), 10));

        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyObject>(this, googleMap);
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);
        renderer = new MyRenderer(this, googleMap, mClusterManager);
        mClusterManager.setRenderer(renderer);

        googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

        addItems();
    }

    private void addItems() {
        // Set some lat/lng coordinates to start with.
        double lat = 51.5145160;
        double lng = -0.1270060;

        // Add ten cluster items in close proximity, for purposes of this example.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            double offset = i / 60d;
            lat = lat + offset;
            lng = lng + offset;
            MyObject offsetItem = new MyObject(lat, lng);
            mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(final Cluster<MyObject> cluster) {
        Marker marker = renderer.getMarker(cluster);
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_newpin));

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your behavior with the demo app. How are you adding your items to the cluster? I would bet that this is more a lifecycle problem rather than a problem with your Renderer. I also would say that you are getting a null `Marker` when calling `renderer.getMarker(cluster);` because the cluster you receive on `onClusterClick(Cluster<MyObject> cluster)` is null.

Comment: cluster is never null. i updated the code above when initializing the `ClusterManager`

Comment: Ok, let me test the behavior of my example with your initialization code

Comment: @antonio My current solution is too keep my own dictionary of <cluster, marker> since they're correctly working in `onClusterRendered`

Comment: I have edited your question with the initialization that is working for me. In my case I am using `OnClusterClickListener` instead of using 'OnClusterItemClickListener'.

Comment: @antonio not sure why i can't get it to return the marker. i just added a worked around

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104919/discussion-between-antonio-and-ono).

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't get `renderer.getMarker(cluster)` to return a marker in that case above. A work around was to create:

```
Map <Cluster<MyObject>, Marker> clusterMarkerMap = new HashMap<>();
```

then add them on the `DefaultClusterRenderer` callback because the marker is never null there:

```
@Override
protected void onClusterRendered(Cluster<MyObject> cluster, Marker marker) {
    super.onClusterRendered(cluster, marker);
    clusterMarkerMap.put(cluster, marker);
}
```

Because the `DefaultClusterManager` clears them when the camera position changes, wipe the cluster marker map before it creates new ones:

```
 googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            // Clear the map here because the markers will be recreated
            // when the manager is notified of a (zoom level) camera change
            if(zoomLevelChanged)
                 clusterMarkerMap.clear();
            mClusterManager.onCameraChange(cameraPosition);
        }
    });
```

Now I can get the marker successfully `clusterMarkerMap.get(cluster)`

Comment: I have the same problem, do you have a more detailed code for onCameraChange ?

Comment: @nikeru8 no sorry don't have access to that code anymore